# changing bootstrap positions/padding doesn't have any effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap/CSS and I would like to know why every change on Bootstrap class works only with luck. This happens to me so much so any tip can be great.

example:

Failing to have drop-down on the left side and some text in the center- **on the same line**.

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel panel-info">
       <div class="dropdown" style="align-content: center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="text-left">Contacts</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel panel-info">
       <div class="dropdown" style="align-content: center">
     
     <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span></button> <h1 class="span7 center"> Contacts </h1>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="dropdown" style="align-content: center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret align-left"></span>Contacts</button>
        </div>
```

Are you asking like this? Above code when executed give the result as a button that has drop-down on the left and some text. Please check and revert.

Comment: no, the text have anything to do with the dropdown. drop down will be in the left side of the panel header and the text will be on the center of the panel header.

Comment: <style>
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: 750px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

Comment: You have to define the above code in the css then it would work